# GAS: Unable to use HtmlService custom dialogs in Firefox

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-api, google-sheets-api

I am trying to create a custom dialogue in Google Apps Script as follows:

```
function onOpen() {   
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi() 
  .createMenu('Custom Menu')
  .addItem('Show dialog', 'showDialog')
  .addToUi();
}
function showDialog() {
  var html = HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('Page')
      .setSandboxMode(HtmlService.SandboxMode.IFRAME)
      .setWidth(400)
      .setHeight(300);
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi() // Or DocumentApp or FormApp.
      .showModalDialog(html, 'My custom dialog');
}
```

Where `Page.html` is:

```
Hello, world! <input type="button" value="Close" onclick="google.script.host.close()" />
```

In Chrome it works as expected. In Firefox 34, the dialogue shows but, when I click on the close button, it does not trigger the callback `google.script.host.close()`.

Firebug reports the error:

```
ReferenceError: google is not defined  userCodeAppPanel (line 1)
```

Comment: It is closing the popup when I click on close button and working perfectly fine for me.

Comment: What browser are you testing this in and it not work. There are a variety of reports of IFRAME not working in all.

Comment: Working as expected here also, copied/pasted everything, does console throws you any error?

Comment: @Jonathon: It works in Chrome, not in FF 34, also starting in safe mode.

Comment: @Antonio. Yes this what has been reported. https://code.google.com/p/google-apps-script-issues/issues/detail?id=4611

Comment: @Kriggs: please, see the question edit

Comment: As Jonathon said, know bug for FF/IE, use Native Sandbox until is fixed. https://code.google.com/p/google-apps-script-issues/issues/detail?id=4617

Comment: @Kriggs: if you make this into an answer, I will close it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a know bug for FF/IE, use Native Sandbox until is fixed and follow the issue in https://code.google.com/p/google-apps-script-issues/issues/detail?id=4617.